# How can I modify the source code of random.c in Linux? And do I have to recompile the kernel to make it take effect?

Tags: linux, random

I want to add some debug info or printf in the random.c in order to look deeply into the Linux random number generator. The entropy in /dev/random and /dev/urandom are both generated by random.c. My questions are:
1. Where I can find the random.c file in Linux 2.6.32?
2. What is the best way to add my modification of random source code into the kernel? Is it OK to just compile random.c and load it as loadable kernel module? Or do I have to recompile and install the kernel to make the new random.c with debug msg somehow take effect? The key point is to make sure that only one copy of random number generator is running in the kernel.

Thank you. Any kind of suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/char/random.c

Comment: Also you want [`printk`](http://www.linuxgrill.com/anonymous/fire/netfilter/kernel-hacking-HOWTO-4.html) not `printf`.

Answer (score 4):

`random.c` is linked directly into the kernel, it isn't built as a module, so you can't just recompile it alone and load it into your kernel, you need to recompile the whole new kernel.

To build the kernel, make sure you have the usual development tools installed: gcc, GNU make, etc. Some distros provide a "build-essentials" or "Development Tools" or similar metapackage that include all of the usual development tools for building the core system packages.

How you build your kernel depends on whether you have any distribution specific patches that are needed to use your system, or if you want to ensure that you use your distro's packaging system to install the kernel. If so, you should probably follow your distro's instructions for building the kernel. For example, [Ubuntu's instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel), [Arch's instructioins](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels), [Fedora's instructions](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel), [CentOS instructions](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel) (likely similar on RHEL 6, Red Hat doesn't provide documentation as they don't support building custom kernels), [SuSE instructions](https://www.suse.com/communities/conversations/compiling-de-linux-kernel-suse-way/).

Otherwise, if you don't mind configuring and installing your kernel manually, you can do it by hand. The following instructions should cover most distros reasonable well, but be sure to check your distro docs in case there are any distro-specific gotchas.

Download the appropriate tarball from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/) and decompress it somewhere. Or if you prefer, check it out using Git. Since you reference 2.6.32, I've included the latest version of 2.6.32 in the below instructions.

```
$ curl -O https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/longterm/v2.6.32/linux-2.6.32.61.tar.xz
$ xzcat linux-2.6.32.61.tar.xz | tar xvf -
$ cd linux-2.6.32.61
# or...
$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
$ cd linux
$ git checkout -b my-branch v2.6.32.61
```

Now you need to do to configure it, build it, and install it. Greg Kroah-Hartmann, a leading kernel developer and stable kernel maintainer, has a free [book](http://www.kroah.com/lkn/) on the subject. I'd recommend reading his book, but if you want a quick rundown, I'll summarize the highlights.

There are several ways to configure it. A good way to start is to just copy your current config in, and then run `make menuconfig` or `make xcconfig` to get a curses or graphical kernel configuration utility that allows you to easily browse and choose the right options (as there may be new options in the new kernel that you are building). Many distros install the config for a given kernel in `/boot/config` or `/boot/config-version` corresponding to the kernel version. Copy that into your source tree as `.config`, and then run `make menuconfig` or `make xconfig`:

```
$ cp /boot/config .config
$ make xconfig
```

After configuring it, I'd recommend adding something to the `EXTRAVERSION` definition in the `Makefile`. The contents of that are tacked on to the version, to help distinguish your modified kernel from the upstream one. I'd recommend setting it to help keep track of which is your modified kernel.

Once it's configured, just build it like anything else. I recommend using `-j` to run a parallel build if you have multiple cores.

```
$ make -j8
```

Now it's built, and you can install it. On most systems, the following works; if not, check out Greg's book or check your distro's documentation:

```
$ sudo make modules_install
$ sudo make install
```

And finally you have to add it to your bootloader (on some systems, `make install` may do this, on some it may not). Depending on whether you use Lilo, Grub, or Grub2, you may need to edit `/etc/lilo.conf` (followed by running `sudo lilo` to install the changes), `/boot/grub/menu.lst`, or `/boot/grub/custom.cfg` (followed by `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` to install the changes). See the relevant documentation for the given bootloader for more details. Generally you want to copy an existing entry and duplicate it, updating it to point to your new kernel. Make sure you leave the existing entries, so you will be able to boot back into your old kernel if this doesn't work.

Now reboot, select your new kernel, and hope your system boots. Woo! You've built your own kernel.

Now that you've made sure you can do that successfully without modifications, you can make your change. You are going to want to modify `drivers/char/random.c`. To print out debugging statements, use `printk()`. It works mostly like `printf()`, though it's not exactly the same so check out the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt) before using it. After you modify, rebuild, and reinstall your new kernel, and reboot into it, you can see the messages printed out with `printk()` statements using the `dmesg` command.

For more information, check out Greg's book that I linked to above, the kernel [README](https://www.kernel.org/doc/readme/README), and [HOWTO](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/HOWTO), browse around the kernel's [Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/) directory, and various other [docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Makefile for it, char driver is not meant to be compiled as a module (random.o is included as `obj-y` in `drivers/char/Makefile`).

You can read more about how to kbuild (kernel build) system works from: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt

Particularly section `--- 3.1 Goal definitions` touches this topic.

1. Generally you can search for files in kernel sources from source cross references (called `LXR`'s). One is for example provided in http://lxr.free-electrons.com/
2. Indeed, you can add your modifications to the `drivers/char/random.c`, and recompile the char driver. After that you will have to rebuild the kernel, so that it will link also your new random.o to the kernel. And then you will have to boot that kernel, that process will depend on your distribution.

Most distributions have good/decent instructions around how to recompile/boot your own kernel.

Comment: Can you guide me how to recompile the random char driver after I modified the random.c?